# SUBSELECT vs. INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Existe alguma recomendação sobre qual das duas é preferível, em termos de performance?

```
SELECT funcionarios.nome
FROM funcionarios
INNER JOIN empresas
  ON empresas.id = funcionarios.empresa_id
WHERE empresas.nome = 'Nome da Empresa'
```

ou

```
SELECT funcionarios.nome
FROM funcionarios
WHERE empresa_id = ( SELECT id
                     FROM empresas
                     WHERE nome = 'Nome da Empresa' )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mistério de como o SqlServer opera internamente é difícil de resolver.

É bem possível que, em alguns casos, a diferença esteja apenas na sintaxe e o Sql Server opere da mesma forma.

Mas a subquery, teoricamente, teria que que ser executada a cada registro da consulta principal enquanto a tabela do join seria tratada de outra maneira. O que me leva a pensar que o join seja mais performático. Mas, segundo o link abaixo, não há diferença de performance quando as consultas são equivalentes.(Como no caso do seu exemplo)

Veja em: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx
Quando as consultas são equivalentes não ha diferença na performance. Mas quando a condição de existência (EXISTS) tem que ser checada a cada registro da query principal, o join tem melhor performance.

No seu caso, pode acontecer um erro se a subquery retornar mais de um registro. A não ser que use  operador "IN"

```
SELECT funcionarios.nome
FROM funcionarios
WHERE empresa_id IN ( SELECT id
                     FROM empresas
                     WHERE nome = 'Nome da Empresa' )
```

Em uma query grande e complexa, subquery pode deixar a consulta mais difícil de ler. Mas é indispensável em outros casos.

Só uso subquery quando a coisa não pode ser feita com Join.

Comment: Em geral o join será mais rápido , o "IN" tem a vantagem de deixar claro a ideia , mas nada que uma comentário não resolva.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o padrão `**Ansi 92**` o correto é utilizar `inner join` ao invés de sub-consulta.

Nem tanto pela performance e sim por padronização.
Porém acredito que o motor do SQL seja um pouco mais otimizado para o inner join do que outras sintaxes.

Comment: SQL 92, disponível para consulta: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito do objetivo da sua consulta, porém lembre-se que acada registro buscado como comparativo na sua consulta com a subquery é estartado novamente o mesmo procedimento, agora com um inner join ele trás as duas tabelas e depois faz a comparações dos valores apresentados no "ON".