# Pegar campo ID de subquery que só puxa nome MySQL

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma query SQL e gostaria de obter 2 campos adicionais de outras tabelas, porém com outros nomes para que não fiquem ambíguas.

Vejam as duas últimas subqueries para resgatar 2 campos como `trtTituloOrigem` e `trtTituloDestino`, respectivamente.

```
SELECT *, 

(SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE tre.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treNomeOrigem, 
(SELECT treEnderecoCidade FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem, 
(SELECT treEnderecoEstado FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem, 

(SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treNomeDestino, 
(SELECT treEnderecoCidade FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
(SELECT treEnderecoEstado FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoEstadoDestino,

(SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = treo.trtId) as trtTituloOrigem,
(SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = tred.trtId) as trtTituloDestino

FROM sistema_voo_operadora vop 

LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 

WHERE ope.opeId = 2;
```

Ao executar essa query, estou recebendo o erro:

> Coluna 'tre.treId' desconhecida em 'where clause'

Acredito que deva ser porque `treId` não existe na *subquery*, já que estou trazendo apenas `trtTitulo`, certo? Porém, como posso trazer estes dois campos?

Só para explicar o contexto todo:

1) Tenho uma tabela de voos globais (`sistema_voo`)
2) Tenho uma tabela de voos por operadora (`sistema_voo_operadora`), guardando o ID do voo global (`vooId`)
3) Na tabela de voos globais, tenho o ID dos trechos de destino e origem. Estes IDs são de uma tabela chamada `sistema_trecho` (`treId`).

Como preciso de uma consulta para trazer ambas no mesmo lugar, para não ter que fazer N consultas, gostaria de trazer todas as infos em um lugar só. Sei que é possível, mas não sei se este é o jeito certo.

**Tentativas:**
Se eu colocar além do `trtTitulo`, um `trtId` nas *subqueries*, elas deixam de funcionar também.

Answer (score 1):

O erro apresentado na consulta é apenas de digitação; na linha que causa o erro 
`(SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE tre.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treNomeOrigem,` o nome da "tabela" está diferente do alias selecionado (`tre` ao invés de `treo`) - a boa notícia é que a *query* está ok.

Quanto a query em si, ela está extremamente custosa para processar; além dos quatro *joins* ela tem oito *subconsultas* (que são executadas para cada campo de cada linha retornada).

Como essas *subqueries* são feitas em cima de apenas duas tabelas, seria mais interessante usá-las em *joins* (*lembrando que usar [join ou subconsulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22891/subselect-vs-inner-join) requer uma análise em cada caso*). Sugiro então usar assim:

```
SELECT *, 
treo.treNome as treNomeOrigem, 
treo.treEnderecoCidade as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem, 
treo.treEnderecoEstado as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem, 

tred.treNome as treNomeDestino, 
tred.treEnderecoCidade as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
tred.treEnderecoEstado as treEnderecoEstadoDestino,

trto.trtTitulo as trtTituloOrigem,
trtd.trtTitulo as trtTituloDestino

FROM sistema_voo_operadora vop 

LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 

LEFT JOIN sistema_trecho treo ON treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId
LEFT JOIN sistema_trecho tred ON tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId

LEFT JOIN sistema_trecho_tipo trto ON trto.trtId = tredo.trtId
LEFT JOIN sistema_trecho_tipo trtd ON trtd.trtId = tred.trtId

WHERE ope.opeId = 2;
```

Ainda assim a *query* não será muito performática; talvez seja melhor rever a estruturação do banco ou uma consulta mais eficiente (a se pensar...)