# Por que ao usar 'IN" para filtrar registros junto com um subselect é retornado registros que tenham, em determinadas colunas, valores iguais

Tags: mysql, sql

Estava estudando e me deparei com isso, sei que o `IN` é como o `OR`,
mas o que não entendi foi esse comando:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers);
```

O retorno é simplesmente os registros da tabela `Customers` que tenham na sua coluna o valor igual à coluna dos registros da tabela `Suppliers`.

Pra mim não fez o menor sentido.

Comment: Para tentar entender por qual motivo você diz "Pra mim não fez o menor sentido." mostre um exemplo de dados de entrada o resultado obtido e qual o resultado esperado. Aparentemente o que você informa como retorno é o comportamento esperado da cláusula `IN`, mas posso não ter entendido sua questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `IN` serve para verificar se a expressão é igual a qualquer um dos valores indicados ([veja a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)).

Por exemplo, supondo que temos essas tabelas:

```
customers
| id | country   |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | Brasil    |
| 2  | Argentina |
| 3  | Paraguai  |
| 4  | Uruguai   |
| 5  | Peru      |

suppliers
| id | country   |
|----|-----------|
| 6  | Peru      |
| 7  | Chile     |
| 8  | Brasil    |
```

Se eu fizer assim:

```
select * from customers where country in ('Brasil', 'Chile', 'Peru');
```

Ele vai verificar na tabela `customers` todos os registros em que a coluna `country` tem um dos valores indicados ("Brasil", "Chile" ou "Peru"). Como "Brasil" e "Peru" tem, mas "Chile" não, a query retorna:

```
| id | country |
|----|---------|
| 1  | Brasil  |
| 5  | Peru    |
```

Mas em vez de valores fixos, [também podemos colocar uma subquery dentro do `IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html). Assim, os valores retornados pela subquery serão usados.

Ou seja, a query abaixo:

```
select country from suppliers;
```

Retorna esses dados:

```
| country |
|---------|
| Peru    |
| Chile   |
| Brasil  |
```

Então se eu fizer:

```
select * from customers
where country in (select country from suppliers);
```

Seria o mesmo que fazer a primeira query acima (`select * from customers where country in ('Brasil', 'Chile', 'Peru')`). A diferença, claro, é que a primeira, com valores fixos, sempre usará aqueles valores específicos. Já esta que usa a subquery poderá trazer resultados diferentes, conforme a tabela `suppliers` é modificada (já que ela sempre usa os valores que a tabela tem no momento em que a query é executada).

---

Sem mais contexto, não dá para explicar muita coisa sobre o que ela significaria, mas pelos nomes das tabelas e colunas, o que dá para inferir é: a query está buscando os clientes (*customers*) dos países onde também há fornecedores (*suppliers*). Se o cliente está um país onde não tem nenhum fornecedor cadastrado (por exemplo, o `customer` com `id` igual a 2, cujo país é a Argentina, e que não tem registro na tabela `suppliers`), ele não é retornado.

Para saber se essa consulta faz sentido ou não, só tendo mais contexto sobre o sistema.

---

Por fim, o mesmo resultado seria obtido com `INNER JOIN`:

```
select c.* from customers c inner join suppliers s on c.country = s.country;
```

Leia mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/112052), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2577174) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22891/112052).

Comment: obg. conseguir compreender, foi uma falta de raciocínio meu

Answer (score 2):

tentando ser didático, o IN [EM] é usado para filtrar de acordo com o array seguinte..
no caso:

> (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers)

essa pesquisa irá retornar um array contendo a lista de países, exemplo:

> ['brasil', 'eua', 'egito']

ou um array contendo os ID's dos respectivos países:

> [1,2,3]

e então será realizada a pesquisa conforme o atributo *Country* estiver contido nesse array retornado..

em suma, seria como realizar a seguinte pesquisa;

```
pesquise todos os atributos
dos clientes
os quais seus respectivos países estão na seguinte lista de países (
  seleção de todos os países dos fornecedores
);
```

equivalente:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM Suppliers
);
```

e então será retornado somente os clientes que moram nos países em que há fornecedores..

Answer (score 0):

Isto faz sentido quando se aplica alguma condição ao subselect, por exemplo filtrar apenas os fornecedores de varejo.

**Em que países temos fornecedores de varejo ?**

```
  SELECT Country  
    FROM Customers
    WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country 
                      FROM Suppliers
                      where segment = 'retail');
```

Isto pode ser feito via join também sempre cabendo uma analise de qual a melhor solução.

Tinha publicado e apagado esta resposta pois julguei incompleta mas após as outras respostas ela acrescenta algo.